# Head div with four sub div

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Goodmorning developers,

I am new in frontend development. I'm stuck with the following problem:

I want to have a head div with 4 sub divs inside the head one. How can I do it with fitting the screen? (see sketch)

[image: sketch]

Kind regards

Comment: What you've tried till now??

Comment: I will suggest  you to use some framework like - bootstrap , foundation etc.. which provides grids for such purpose and also make it responsive for various screen size.. http://getbootstrap.com/  ,  http://foundation.zurb.com/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am using a framework from the company itself. I already made a tab menu. In each subdivs I have to make a bar chart. It is like a dashboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need this please check:

See [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wwkw1f3o/4/)

```css
.container {
  border: 3px solid;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.custom_box {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.custom_box1 {
  border: 3px solid;
  float: left;
  margin: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 35%;
}
.custom_box2 {
  border: 3px solid;
  float: left;
  margin: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 55%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="custom_box">
  <div class="custom_box1">
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="custom_box2">
    <h1>2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="custom_box">
  <div class="custom_box1">
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="custom_box2">
    <h1>2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are the best! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9Lum94me/

There are other ways as well with CSS [floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float), [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) and [table-cell](http://www.sitepoint.com/solving-layout-problems-css-table-property/) which you can explore.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">Column 1</div>
    <div class="column">Column 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">Column 3</div>
    <div class="column">Column 4</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.row{
  padding: 10px;
}
.row .column{
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 45%; min-height: 150px;  border: 1px solid gray; margin: 0 4% 0 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** 
You will have to manage the widths of the columns as per needs.

Answer (score 0):

A bootstrap responsive example without any style...(Except bordering).

Fiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/4CrU6/5/)

```css
.content{
  border:2px solid green;
  height:100px;
  width:92%;
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row" style="border:1px solid blue;">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
  
    <div class="row no-gutter-2">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="content">Header1</div>
        </div>   
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="content">Header2</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="content">Header3</div>
        </div>   
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="content">Header4</div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

To test the responsiveness, plz re-size the browser window.
Above example is responsive on small, medium and large scale.
Please run the snippet on full page.